# How to import ckeditor/jsp taglibs in a Grails app

Tags: jsp, grails, ckeditor, taglib

I'm using the ckeditor plugin and have

```
plugins {
  compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"
  ...
}
```

in my Buildconfig.

I have run refresh-dependencies and thought I would be ready to go to use the ckeditor taglib. I added the the following to my gsp like it is suggested by the official integration guide of ckeditor:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>
```

But this gives me the error: "Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://ckeditor.com""

Is there something I have to take care of when using jsp tags in a gsp file? Or what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you seen this page: http://stefanogualdi.github.io/grails-ckeditor/docs/guide/gettingStarted.html#usage ? It explains how to use ckeditor plugin in Grails.

Comment: Yes I have seen this. But it doesn't work either. "<ckeditor:resources/>" gives me "Unknown tag (ckeditor:resources)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I erroneously installed

```
grails install-plugin ckeditor
```

So I did

```
grails uninstall-plugin ckeditor
```

In BuildConfig.groovy, I removed version 4.4.1.0 and put:

```
plugins {
    ...
    compile ":ckeditor:3.6.6.1.0"
    ...
}
```

It doesn't seem to work with 4.4.1.0.
In main.gsp I put in the head section:

```
<ckeditor:resources/>
```

It is yellow underlined in Eclipse and it says: "Unknown tag(ckeditor:resources)" but it works anyway. In some .gsp file I have yellow underlined as well with unknown tag:

```
<ckeditor:editor />
```

That renders the ckeditor.

Comment: I mark this as answer as it provides more help than i could deliver^^

Answer (score 0):

It works now. No clue why. The error messages can be ignored obviously.